# .htaccess [L] and [end] flags

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What is the difference between `[L]` and `[end]`?
`last` and `end` are the same, aren't they?

In my `.htaccess` I have

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# I use this only to test my $_SERVER variables
RewriteRule ^phpinfo phpinfo.php [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?data=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and the behaviour of the both `end` and `L` is the same. I suppose that in a more complicated example it won't be, so can you give me such an example?

From the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html):

> The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In
>   most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules
>   will be processed.

and

> Using the [END] flag terminates not only the current round of rewrite
>   processing (like [L]) **but also prevents any subsequent rewrite
>   processing from occurring in per-directory (htaccess) context.**

What does this mean?

Comment: See [my explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47470720/444255). Unless you see benefits from multiple rounds or rewriting, always put an END to the End. :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It relates to the global apache configuration. If you use `[L]` in httpd.conf then there still is a chance to apply some rules in .htaccess. But if you use `[END]` the game is over and .htaccess can not add anything

Comment: Does the `L` flag prevent all rules I have written?

Comment: [L] prevents further rules on the same level, [END] prevents rules on the same and higher levels.