# Apache 2.4 - transparently redirect to subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am transparently redirecting every request(html, css, js,...) to a subfolder `_site` (where my static [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) site sits...)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_site.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  _site/$1 [L]
```

That basically works. Although I find it rather strange, that I have to use the Rewrite condition, to block iterations:

> AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if ...

#### After all, I am using [[L] for last](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/de/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l), so how come, I end up in recursions?!?

If I try to prevent direct access to the site-folder (like `example.com/_site/favicon.ico`), be prepending this first line:

```
RewriteRule ^_site.* - [R=403,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_site.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  _site/$1 [L]
```

Then, also  on *legitimate* access (`example.com/favicon.ico`) I get a 403!

Apparently, every request takes another round. The legitimate ones, then in “round 2” match the forbidden rule. So, what's wrong here?

**Why doesn't „last“ mean „last“?** (did something change, i.e. between Apache 2.2 and 2.4? as quite a few thing changed on `.htaccess` there...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Cough**, „Last“ doesn't quite mean „last“. It only means

> „quit rewriting within this file now, ignore the rest of the lines“.

But it also means

> „re-run the whole htaccess-thing with that new (rewritten) url.

(Something you might not notice for YEARS, if your rewrite rules are too specific to trigger recursions... even, if in all honesty, [its in the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l))

So, happy recursion, everyone. To truly put an end to things, [guess what](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  _site/$1 [END]
```

... respectively in my extended version:

```
RewriteRule ^_site.* - [R=403,NC,END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_site.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  _site/$1 [END]
```

( `.. ,L,END` doesn't hurt, but `END` implies `L`)